# What is the exact meaning of $C^{\infty} (\mathbb{R})$ ? what is application i mean why we used this symbol?

Tags: real-analysis, notation

I have  some  confusion

What  is  the  exact  meaning of $C^{\infty} (\mathbb{R})$ ?   what  is  application   i mean   why   we  used  this  symbol ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ stands for the set of all functions from $\mathbb R$ into itself such that all derivative ($f',f'',f''',\ldots$) exist. It is used when we want to talk about these functions.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that generally there is some assumed algebraic structure on this set (it is a vector space and a ring for easy examples).

Comment: thanks u @ jose sir....sir  one  more  requested  u  pliz  look  this also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2893166/is-the-inverse-function-is-differentiable-at-1